# How to define functions from an index set to an indefinite set of domains?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to define sth like

```
list([[i0,i1,i2,i3, ..., ik]] for i0 in T[0] for i1 in T[1] for i2 in T[2] for i3 in T[3] for ...)
```

as k is indefinite, I cannot do this like

```
list([[i0,i1,i2,i3]] for i0 in T[0] for i1 in T[1] for i2 in T[2] for i3 in T[3]).
```

Is there a general solution?

Many thanks!

Comment: Is [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Your nested `for`s will make a Cartesian product of the sublists in `T`. [Itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) has a [`product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function that will give you an iterator of these values, which you can use like:

```
from itertools import product
T = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10,11, 12]]
p = product(*T)
for i in p:
    print(i)
```

> (1, 4, 7, 10)
>   (1, 4, 7, 11)
>   (1, 4, 7, 12)
>   (1, 4, 8, 10)
>   (1, 4, 8, 11)
>   (1, 4, 8, 12)
>   (1, 4, 9, 10)
>   (1, 4, 9, 11)
>   ...
>   (3, 6, 9, 10)
>   (3, 6, 9, 11)
>   (3, 6, 9, 12)

Of course you can also pass it to `list()` if want the values in a list.

Comment: It works. Given a complex list P with indefinite length and form like [ [1,1,1], [1,2,3], [4,5]], I defined, as you suggested, PJ = list(x for x in product(*P)). Thanks!